# use constructor name as index signature for return type

Tags: typescript, generics, angular7

Is it possible to use the `name` property of a constructor function as index signature, respectivly as property name?

#### Example

I want to have a generic mapping function for server reponses. Those could include multiple entities.
E.g

```
const serverResponse = {
    User: {...},
    UserGroup: {...},
    ...someServerResponseStuff...
}
```

wished result:

```
const mappedResponse: {User: User, UserGroup: UserGroup} = mapToEntity(serverResponse, User, UserGroup);
```

achieved result:

```
const mappedResponse: {[key: string]: User | UserGroup} = mapToEntity(serverResponse, User, UserGroup);
```

#### current mapToEntity Implementation

```
type ConstructorFunction<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T;
```

For better readability there are only two specified constructor function parameters. Threre would be more in the real implementation.

```
export function mapToEntity<A>(serverResponse: IServerResponse, cFn1: ConstructorFunction<A>): A[];
export function mapToEntity<A, B>(serverResponse: IServerResponse, cFn1: ConstructorFunction<A>, cFn2: ConstructorFunction<B>): {[key: string]: A[] | B[]}; // specify index signatures here
export function mapToEntity<A, B>(serverResponse: IServerResponse, cFn1: ConstructorFunction<A>, cFn2?: ConstructorFunction<B>, ...constructorFunctions: ConstructorFunction<any>[]): A[] | {[key: string]: any[]} {

  let cArray: ConstructorFunction<any>[] = [cFn1];

  if(cFn2) {
    cArray.push(cFn2);
  }

  cArray = [...cArray, ...constructorFunctions];

  if (cArray.length > 1) {
    const result: {[key: string]: any[]} = {};
    for (const constructorFunction of cArray) {
      const modelName: string = constructorFunction.name;
      result[modelName] = new constructorFunction(serverResponse[modelName]);
    }
    return result;
  } 

  const x = new cFn1(serverResponse[modelName]);
  return x; 
}
```

#### wished definition of second overload

```
export function mapToEntity<A, B>(serverResponse: IServerResponse, cFn1: ConstructorFunction<A>, cFn2: ConstructorFunction<B>): {cFn1.name: A[], cFn2.name: B[]}; // specify index signatures here
```

or more likely

```
export function mapToEntity<A, B>(serverResponse: IServerResponse, cFn1: ConstructorFunction<A>, cFn2: ConstructorFunction<B>): {ConstructorName<cFn1<A>>: A[], ConstructorName<cFn2<B>>: B[]}; // specify index signatures here
```

### Edit

Best thing I got until now is to rename the result with object destructoring.
But this is still far from ideal

```
export function mapToEntity<A, B>(serverResponse: IServerResponse, cFn1: ConstructorFunction<A>, cFn2: ConstructorFunction<B>): {entity1: A[], entity2: B[]};
```

```
const { 'entity1': user, 'entity2': userGroup } = mapToEntity(fakeResponse, User, UserGroup);
```

### Edit2

I found a solution, I could live with

```
export function mapToEntity<A, B>(serverResponse: IServerResponse, cFn1: ConstructorFunction<A>, cFn2: ConstructorFunction<B>): [A[], B[]];
```

```
const [user, userGroup] = mapToEntity(fakeResponse, User, UserGroup);
```

You could also save it in one variable and get type safe properties out of the array

```
    const test: [User[], UserGroup[]] = mapToEntity(fakeResponse, User, UserGroup);
    const x = test[1]; // has type UserGroup[]
```